# Announcing a Pro Tempore election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Medical Sciences Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://health.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **October 22** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Between now and October 22, users can decide whether to nominate themselves. Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- During the nomination period, users may nominate themselves and answer any questions that might have been asked on meta.
- On October 29, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on November 6.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should.)

## Medical professionals preferred

This isn't something we normally concern ourselves with, but given the nature of this site, medical professionals are encouraged to run if interested. We won't be checking your licence, obviously, but it would really help evaluate answers and effectively moderate the site.

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: We have at least one moderator at this time that is not a medical professional according their profile.

Answer (score 5):

Question: is there any chance we could select two or three?  Our site has several professionals and student professionals, but none of them have a large amount of time to dedicate.

Comment: We discussed that, and michaelpri and I are good to handle the bulk of the work for flag handling, but we would like a medical professional (Even on a limited time basis) to handle items or provide clarification on cases where the medical knowledge is needed to assess the question.